# How do I undo the focus (unfocus) of a cell in a table (Ext.grid.Panel)?

Tags: extjs

The table (`Ext.grid.Panel`) cell is not an object that could be invoked with the `blur()` method.

The method table `Ext.grid.Panel.blur()` also does not.

When we click on the row, it is in focus (cell of this row is in focus).
How to programmatically remove this focus?

Comment: You want to remove the focus altogether or just on demand?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to highlight row after row click use [disableSelection](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-disableSelection) config.If you have any other requirement specify it.

Comment: No, I just need the selection of the rows!

Comment: Then why you dont use any selection model dude.It will automatically handle selection deselection.Is this what you want ?

Comment: I need an unfocus cell. Selection is not unfocus)))